# How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following script. And I want to make both maps appear on the page, but no matter what I try I can only get the first map initialize() to display... the second one doesn't. Any suggestions? (also, I can't add it in the code, but the first map is being displayed in `<div id="map_canvas"></div><div id="route"></div>`
Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Create a directions object and register a map and DIV to hold the 
// resulting computed directions

var map;
var directionsPanel;
var directions;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801), 15);
  directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
  directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
  directions.load("from: Armonk Fire Department, Armonk NY to: <?php echo $LastCallGoogleAddress;?> ");

  map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
}

</script> 


<div id="map_canvas2" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
<div id="route2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Create a directions object and register a map and DIV to hold the 
// resulting computed directions

var map2;
var directionsPanel2;
var directions2;

function initialize2() {
  map2 = new GMap(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"));
  map2.setCenter(new GLatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801), 15);
  directionsPanel2 = document.getElementById("route2");
  directions2 = new GDirections(map2, directionsPanel2);
  directions2.load("from: ADDRESS1 to: ADDRESS2 ");

  map2.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
  map2.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
}

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadmaps(){
    initialize();
    initialize2();  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here is how I have been able to generate multiple maps on the same page using `Google Map API V3`. Kindly note that this is an off the cuff code that addresses the issue above.

The HTML bit

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:500px; margin-left:80px;"></div>
<div id="map_canvas2" style="width:700px; height:500px; margin-left:80px;"></div>
```

Javascript for map initialization

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map, map2;

function initialize(condition) {
    // create the maps
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), myOptions);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but still one of the map doesn't load.

Comment: Philar's answer works.
Just remember to also apply the css height and width to the new div with the second map!! I just lost half an hour wondering why the second map won't appear and there were no errors and my dive had height and width zer0 :|

Answer (score 14):

I have just finished adding Google Maps to my company's CMS offering.  My code allows for more than one map in a page.

**Notes:**

- I use jQuery
- I put the address in the content and then parse it out to dynamically generate the map
- I include a Marker and an InfoWindow in my map

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block maps first">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="map_canvas">
            <div class="infotext">
                <div class="location">Middle East Bakery & Grocery</div>
                <div class="address">327 5th St</div>
                <div class="city">West Palm Beach</div>
                <div class="state">FL</div>
                <div class="zip">33401-3995</div>
                <div class="country">USA</div>
                <div class="phone">(561) 659-4050</div>
                <div class="zoom">14</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block maps last">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="map_canvas">
            <div class="infotext">
                <div class="location">Global Design, Inc</div>
                <div class="address">3434 SW Ash Pl</div>
                <div class="city">Palm City</div>
                <div class="state">FL</div>
                <div class="zip">34990</div>
                <div class="country">USA</div>
                <div class="phone"></div>
                <div class="zoom">17</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $maps = $('.block.maps .content .map_canvas');
    $maps.each(function(index, Element) {
        $infotext = $(Element).children('.infotext');

        var myOptions = {
            'zoom': parseInt($infotext.children('.zoom').text()),
            'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;
        var infowindow;
        var address = $infotext.children('.address').text() + ', '
                + $infotext.children('.city').text() + ', '
                + $infotext.children('.state').text() + ' '
                + $infotext.children('.zip').text() + ', '
                + $infotext.children('.country').text()
        ;
        var content = '<strong>' + $infotext.children('.location').text() + '</strong><br />'
                + $infotext.children('.address').text() + '<br />'
                + $infotext.children('.city').text() + ', '
                + $infotext.children('.state').text() + ' '
                + $infotext.children('.zip').text()
        ;
        if (0 < $infotext.children('.phone').text().length) {
            content += '<br />' + $infotext.children('.phone').text();
        }

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                myOptions.center = results[0].geometry.location;
                map = new google.maps.Map(Element, myOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: $infotext.children('.location').text()
                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({'content': content});
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(event) {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            } else {
                alert('The address could not be found for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason every time I use this, it just makes the 2 div's disappear. I'm using literally the exact same code as above. How would I make this a `jQuery.noConflict()` function?

Comment: @Jared - are you linking to the Google Maps API JavaScript before calling your local JavaScript code? - http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: @Mike - You mean an example web site that is using the code? Here's one: http://www.habitatmartin.org/p/89/contact-us

Comment: @Jared - I am not familiar with using `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Also make sure to remove 'async defer' from the link to the Google script.  Else you will get something like 'google is not defined'.

Answer (score 13):

OP wanted two specific maps, but if you'd like to have a dynamic number of maps on one page (for instance a list of retailer locations) you need to go another route. The standard implementation of Google maps API defines the map as a global variable, this won't work with a dynamic number of maps. Here's my code to solve this without global variables:

```
function mapAddress(mapElement, address) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElement), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

Just pass the ID and address of each map to the function to plot the map and mark the address.

Comment: Good answer this is much better not as hard coded as other solutions and very reusable thank you Daniel Hedenström

Comment: Concise, clear and very reusable. Thanks - this helped me lots.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to load dynamic number of google maps, with dynamic locations. So I ended up with something like this. Hope it helps. I add LatLng as data-attribute on map div.

So, just create divs with class "maps". Every map canvas can than have a various IDs and LatLng like this. Of course you can set up various data attributes for zoom and so...

Maybe the code might be cleaner, but it works for me pretty well.

```
<div id="map123" class="maps" data-gps="46.1461154,17.1580882"></div>
<div id="map456" class="maps" data-gps="45.1461154,13.1080882"></div>

  <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        // Get all map canvas with ".maps" and store them to a variable.
        var maps = document.getElementsByClassName("maps");

        var ids, gps, mapId = '';

        // Loop: Explore all elements with ".maps" and create a new Google Map object for them
        for(var i=0; i<maps.length; i++) {

          // Get ID of single div
          mapId = document.getElementById(maps[i].id);

          // Get LatLng stored in data attribute. 
          // !!! Make sure there is no space in data-attribute !!!
          // !!! and the values are separated with comma !!!
          gps = mapId.getAttribute('data-gps');

          // Convert LatLng to an array
          gps = gps.split(",");

          // Create new Google Map object for single canvas 
          map = new google.maps.Map(mapId, {
            zoom: 15,
            // Use our LatLng array bellow
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(gps[0]), parseFloat(gps[1])),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
            }
          });

          // Create new Google Marker object for new map
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            // Use our LatLng array bellow
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(gps[0]), parseFloat(gps[1])),
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another example if you have the long and lat, in my case using Umbraco Google Map Datatype package and outputting a list of divs with class "map" eg.

```
<div class="map" id="UK">52.21454000000001,0.14044490000003407,13</div>
```

my JavaScript using Google Maps API v3 based on [Cultiv Razor examples](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cultiv-razor-examples)

```
$('.map').each(function (index, Element) {
    var coords = $(Element).text().split(",");
    if (coords.length != 3) {
        $(this).display = "none";
        return;
    }
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: parseFloat(coords[2]),
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(Element, myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
});
```

Comment: Been mucking around for ages and putting this off, this answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 5):

Taken from These examples - [guide](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1957-displaying-multiple-google-maps-on-one-page) , [implementation](http://wccfl.com/f5x/maps.html) .

1. set your `<div>`'s with the appropriate `id`
2. include the Google Map options with `foundation` calling.
3. include `foundation` and `rem` js lib .

**Example -**

**index.html -**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 medium-6 ">
      <div id="map_canvas" class="google-maps">
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="large-6 medium-6 ">
      <div id="map_canvas_2" class="google-maps"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/google_maps_options.js"></script>
<script src="/js/rem.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery(function(){
       setTimeout(initializeGoogleMap,700);
   });
</script>
```

**google_maps_options.js -**

```
function initializeGoogleMap()
{
    $(document).foundation();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.561287,-81.444465);
    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.507561,-81.482359);

    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var myOptions2 =
    {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);


    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Barnett Park"
   });

    var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: latlng2,
        map: map2,
        title:"Bill Fredrick Park at Turkey Lake"
    });


}
```

Comment: I think you might be missing your first declaration of myOptions (just in case someone tries to copy/paste this solution as it looks quite good)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a div with id="map_canvas", you only have id="map_canvas2" and id="route2".  The div ids need to match the argument in the GMap() constructor.

Comment: I have map_canvas. It wasn't letting me put it in the code within the question for some reason, but I do have it in the page, so that's not the problem... the map in map_canvas is the one showing up, but not the map in map_canvas2

Answer (score 2):

You could try nex approach
css

```
 .map {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

HTML

```
@foreach(var map in maps)
{
  <div id="map-@map.Id" lat="@map.Latitude" lng="@map.Longitude" class="map">
  </div>
}
```

JavaScript

```
 <script>
    var maps = [];
    var markers = [];
    function initMap() {
        var $maps = $('.map');
        $.each($maps, function (i, value) {
            var uluru = { lat: parseFloat($(value).attr('lat')), lng: parseFloat($(value).attr('lng')) };

            var mapDivId = $(value).attr('id');

            maps[mapDivId] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapDivId), {
                zoom: 17,
                center: uluru
            });

            markers[mapDivId] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: maps[mapDivId]
            });
        })
    }
</script>

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ru-Ru&key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had one especific issue, i had a Single Page App and needed to show different maps, in diferent divs, one each time. I solved it in not a very beautiful way but a functionally way. Instead of hide the DOM elements with **display** property i used the **visibility** property to do it. With this approach Google Maps API had no trouble about know the dimensions of the divs where i had instantiated the maps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maps_qty;
for (var i = 1; i <= maps_qty; i++)
    {
        $(".append_container").append('<div class="col-lg-10 grid_container_'+ (i) +'" >' + '<div id="googleMap'+ i +'" style="height:300px;"></div>'+'</div>');
        map = document.getElementById('googleMap' + i);
        initialize(map,i);
    }

// Intialize Google Map with Polyline Feature in it.

function initialize(map,i)
    {
        map_index = i-1;
        path_lat_long = [];
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850)
        };

        var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3
        };

        //Push element(google map) in an array of google maps
        map_array.push(new google.maps.Map(map, mapOptions));
        //For Mapping polylines to MUltiple Google Maps
        polyline_array.push(new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions));
        polyline_array[map_index].setMap(map_array[map_index]);
    }

// For Resizing Maps Multiple Maps.

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function()
    {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

map.setZoom( map.getZoom() - 1 );
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() + 1 );
```

Comment: .append_container is the class of the container in which we want to display multiple maps.

Answer (score -2):

Take a Look at this Bundle for Laravel that I Made Recently !

---

https://github.com/Maghrooni/googlemap

---

it helps you to create one or multiple maps in your page ! 

you can find the class on

```
src/googlemap.php
```

Pls Read the readme file first  and  don't forget to pass different ID  if you want to have multiple Maps in one page

Comment: Why do you **keep** emboldening **random** words?

Comment: @MattFletcher, it was a bad habit, thank you for mentioning. just finished editing it.