# A variable number of Google maps on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, variables, code-reuse

I'm loading multiple Google maps inside a page using ajax. They are dynamically generated vary in number of maps rendered per page. I found a partial solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3/4075663#4075663).

My problem with the solution is that I don't have a fixed number of maps. Is there a way to dynamically generate the names of the variables that store the map objects (map1, map2, etc)? Is there a better solution that doesn't involve generating variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use arrays in javascript. Something like this:

```
    var mapObjects;

    function geAllMapDivs() {
        var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'), i, L;
        var mapDivs = [];
        for(i=0, L=allDivs.length; i<L; i++) {
            if (allDivs[i].id.substring(0,4) == "map_") {
                mapDivs.push(allDivs[i]);
            }
        }
        return mapDivs;
    }

    function createMaps() {
        var mapDivs = getAllMapDivs(), i, L;
        mapObjects = [];
        for(i=0, L=mapDivs.length; i<L; i++) {
            mapObjects.push(new google.maps.Map(mapDivs[i], myOptions)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: After that, how will I reference them?

Comment: `mapObjects[0]`, `mapObjects[1]` and so on.  After the `createMaps()` function completes, you can reference `mapObjects` just the same way that you referenced `mapDivs` *inside the `createMaps` function.* They are both arrays of objects. (Though `mapDivs` is known only inside the `createMaps` function)