# Listener for Google Maps (onLoaded) in Android

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview, listener

I'm trying to use the method `zoomToSpan()` from the Google MapView, but as I have read, this only works, if the MapView is fully loaded, so I want to know if there is a possibility to add a Listener to my Mapview to get a message, when it is done.

Answer (score -2):

I use `addListener` to place an infowindow on my maps after the map loads, so that that the map will reposition and display the entire infowindow. I do this on a standard web browser, and I am not sure that it applies to the Android platform:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(event) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    // only do this the first time tiles are loaded
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
});
```

Here's my response to another question where you can see more of the code: [How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3/4081814#4081814)

Comment: @soren.qvist - I am aware of that, and I stated in my response that I wasn't sure if it applied to the Android platform. No-one else has even attempted to answer this question.