# google maps two maps on same page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

well i'm using this code for my website now -> http://bootply.com/98836

but i need two of maps in same page
so i duplicate it and just change 'div id'

first map is

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<span id="map-input"> address </span>
```

and second map is

```
<div id="maps-canvas"></div>
<span id="maps-input"> address </span>
```

and i made .js for it

but its not working
its gonna two address in first map

how can i solve it ???????

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many maps on a page as you want, aslong as you don't use an ID more than once.
You have 2 of #maps-canvas, so javascript will not know which one you mean.

Change the IDs, and create a map on each div:

```
<div id="map-canvas-first"></div>
<span id="map-input-first"> address </span>


<div id="maps-canvas-second"></div>
<span id="maps-input-second"> address </span>


mapFirst = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-first'),mapOptions);
mapSecond = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-second'),mapOptions);
```

Comment: his id's are unique map-canvas and maps-canvas are different.

Answer (score 0):

please do not use an id twice. IDs are unique

Maybe this helps:

[How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3)

Comment: He didn't use any ID twice

Comment: well, according to his post, he did. The code he posted for first and second map has same ids

Comment: `#map-canvas` and `#maps-canvas` are not the same