# Redraw directive on changing page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for Google Maps

```
var link = function(scope, element) {

    var map;

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(..., ...);

    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute("id", "map");
    element.prepend(el);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link
};
```

And I use this directive on two pages:

Page1:

```
<map></map>
```

Page2:

```
<map></map>
```

When I change page `$location.path('/page2');`Map div is empty. First time map's loading correct.

How can I update map? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> You can have as many maps on a page as you want, aslong as you don't use an ID more than once. You have 2 of #maps-canvas, so javascript will not know which one you mean.

[google maps two maps on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700087/google-maps-two-maps-on-same-page)