# How to load three different maps to different views at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Here I have 3 different divs and what I need is to load three maps to them. My javascript looks like

```
function initialize() {
var map_canvas1 = document.getElementById('map_canvas1');
var map_canvas2 = document.getElementById('map_canvas2');
var map_canvas3 = document.getElementById('map_canvas3');

var map_options1 = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map_options2 = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map_options3 = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
};
var map1 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas1, map_options1);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas2, map_options2);
var map3 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas3, map_options3);
```

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

My HTML body looks like

```
      <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#map_canvas1">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map_canvas2">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map_canvas3">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="map_canvas1" class="map_canvas">
            </div>
            <div id="map_canvas2" class="map_canvas">
            </div>
            <div id="map_canvas3" class="map_canvas">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And my style

```
.map_canvas {
  height: 600px;
}
```

But the 2nd and 3rd maps not displaying correctly. 
[image: First Tab][image: Second Tab][image: Third Tab]

Comment: What are CSS styling rules for `map_canvas1X`?

Comment: Check I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i have this problem, i usualy fix this by adding

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This puts the map back in full width and height.

Comment: Where to use it? Inside the initialize() ?

Comment: As long as it's used after 'creating' the map i think. I would place it when someone clicks on a tab, so you know they need that map.

Comment: Map disappears after calling the resize event.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and the only thing I changed for it to work was to define a width in the .map_canvas class!
    .map_canvas{ width:800px;height:600px; }