# google-map element throws error upon creation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-web-component

> *Downvote people: Note that this question is n̲o̲t̲ about Google Maps API V3. `<google-map>` is a [GoogleWebComponent](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents) that displays a map automagically upon declaration in dom.*

---

```
var map = document.createElement("google-map");
```

By only executing this line, it throws an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: latitude must be a number

I don't even get a chance to set the latitude property.

Is this because I'm creating multiple `google-map`s (in different `dom-module`s) within the same page? If not, why is this happening and how do I solve this?

---

### Added

Even doing something like this still yields the same error:

```
var map = document.createElement("span");
    map.innerHTML = "<google-map latitude='1'></google-map>";
```

Comment: In your google map initialization, do you set required parameters? :O

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3

Comment: @ThibaultBach What do you mean by that? I'm setting the parameters right after that line, however aren't every property optional? ([doc](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map))

Comment: Hum ... can you get your code? Normaly, create multiple map on the same page don't make trouble...

Comment: @ThibaultBach That line is literally the only line (in related portion of the code)...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, I have been trying to replicate the problem you are experiencing, but to no avail. The code I've been working with is http://pastebin.com/bXaANTHs - perhaps you could provide more context for the code you've provided? It would help to know where this line is, when it is being called, etc.

Comment: @VartanSimonian I have made a demo [here](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/160#issuecomment-111642538). By simply creating a `google-map` element the error is thrown. It shouldn't matter where I call it right? It's just simply creating an dom element.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Looks like you got [your answer](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/160#issuecomment-111644618)! Perhaps try attaching the element to the document DOM first and then set its `innerHTML`?

Comment: @VartanSimonian But how can I attach the element when it already failed at the `createElement` line? Or were you referring to the modifying `innerHTML` trick?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I was referring to the `innerHTML` trick. I was thinking you could try creating a `<span>` tag or something of the sort, but attach it to the document *first* before setting its innerHTML.

Comment: @VartanSimonian I tried that, but that doesn't work even when I make sure the `span` is already attached in the dom.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Darn. I think we might have to wait for the patch to the issue.. unless someone that knows more stops by and leaves a better answer!