# Problems with Multiple Google Maps on One Page

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, maps, smarty

Hi i have problems to display more than one Google maps on one page

The first map shows correctly but the second doesnt show

I use Smarty to display templates. The results comes from a db. Can anybody check the code and help me to display more than one map

```
{foreach item=row  from=$adress}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      function initialize() {
                        var position = new google.maps.LatLng({$row->lat}, {$row->longi});
                        var myOptions = {
                          zoom: 12,
                          center: position,
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(
                            document.getElementById("map_canvas{$row->site_id}"),
                            myOptions);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: position,
                            map: map,
                            title:"This is the place."
                        });  

                        var contentString = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>!';
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                          infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });

                      }

                    </script>
                  <div id="map_canvas{$row->site_id}" style="width:300px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you check the code statically without the programs {} etc..

Comment: How do you mean that?

Comment: i meant copy paste two blocks of codes one for map_canvas1 and another map_canvas2 for the second map.. then find out its giving error or not. An example code:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3

Comment: You can't have multiple functions with the same name (you have an `initialize` function for each map)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your html code:-

```
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<H1 align="center">Two Google maps side-by-side</h1>
<div id="map_canvas1" style="top: 10px; left: 25px; width:210px; height:220px; float: left"></div>
<div id="map_canvas2" style="top: 10px; left: 75px; width:210px; height:220px"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>


    function initialize()
    {
        <?php 

    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){

    ?>

        var latlng<?php echo $i ?> = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520266,73.856406);

        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng<?php echo $i; ?>,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        var map<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas<?php echo $i ?>"), myOptions);



        var myMarker<?php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: latlng<?php echo $i; ?>,
            map: map<?php echo $i; ?>,
            title:"Pune"
       });

    <?php } ?>

    }


    </script>
```

I know you are using different programming language to define your code. But the logic i hope you understood.

Comment: i dont understand to do that. i use now static google map images with marker to display