# Mutiple google maps on single page

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to display multiple google maps on a single page. Exact amount of map instances can vary per page. I found this code in an answer to another question which seems exactly what I need:

```
function mapAddress(mapElement, address) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElement), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22328509/2740023

I'm uncertain about how I'd edit this code with the correct variables to make it work. I have access to lat and long variables as well as an address in text string format. Just where exactly do I insert those in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you posted looks like it has some code to geocode an address. If you want to display 2 maps, you will need to create two maps objects and put them in their own div. Please see sample code:

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

CSS

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#map2 {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var map;
var map2;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
   zoom: 8
 });
 map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
  center: {lat: 30.2672, lng: -97.7431},
  zoom: 8
 });
}
```

I have a sample of this on a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/eb5owrdc/1/

Please note that you will need to insert your own API key for the sample to work.

I hope this helps!