# mysql table containing latitude, longitude and Google maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, maps

Is it possible to have about 20 Google maps on one webpage? 
I have a page with [all matches of all the teams for the week selected](https://www.doskobeveren.be/acj/?kalweek=35). I want after each match a map with the location of the home team. With the Google maps API I only succeed to show the map for the first record, for the second record I have to use a link. I need to work with lat,long because using the postaddress is not always accurate.

I have to search the matches in 3 tables. 
The lat and long coordinates are stored in a table as lat,long, I echo this lat,long to the Function myMap then I split it and assign the values with parseFloat().

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px"></div>
<script>
<!--  
function myMap() {
    var gpsf1 = "<phpcode><?php echo $coordf1; ?></phpcode>";
    var values = gpsf1.split(",");
    var v1 = parseFloat(values[0]);
    var v2 = parseFloat(values[1]);
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(v1,v2);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 17};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
    marker.setMap(map);
}
//--></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=myMap"></script>
```

A [question posted some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3) has been answered by Daniel Hedenström concerning a dynamic number of maps on one page. In fact this is what I need.
The function that Daniel has used is:

```
    function mapAddress(mapElement, address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElement), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

Then he says: Just pass the ID and address of each map to the function to plot the map and mark the address.

Where to place the script? 
How to format the call to the function and where to place the call?

Comment: you  mean 20 maps one each in a  separated  div ? or a map with 20 marker .. one for each position?

Comment: why not use single map and 20 marker??? why separate Map?

Comment: I prefer separated divs, if possible.