# Could not load multiple Maps in my React Application using custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I built a React component to display a Google Map using Map Api in my React Application.
In index.html I loaded the Google Maps Api script as follows

**index.html**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY %>&libraries=places"></script>
...
```

and then this is how my component looks like

**map.js**

```
"use strict";
import React, {Component} from "react";

class MapComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.props.mapId), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 45.4642035, lng:  9.189982}
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.lat){
      this.map.setCenter({lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng})
      if(this.marker)
      {
        this.marker.setPosition({lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng});
      }
      else
      {
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          zoom: 11,
          position: {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng},
          map: this.map,
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="map-container">
        <div className={ (this.props.address)?'map-info':'' }>{ this.props.address }</div>
        <div id={this.props.mapId}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default MapComponent;
```

If i render one map everything works fine, but when I try to render multiple maps in the same view only the first one shows up.
I have no errors in the console.
Any clue on where I am making a mistake, or on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Per the 2nd comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075663/1819684 "remember to also apply the css height and width to ... the second map"

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, i forgot to set the map height in my css. I will do it inline. Thanks!!