# Want multiple google direction map on single page

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am creating a google driving direction map for my application in which i want to add multiple maps on single page who has different routs. I tried but my map is going overridden.I get the route info in array and just extracted array through for each

```
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:100%;"></div>

<script>
  var id=1;
  function initMap() {

    console.log("map initiated");

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      center: {lat:<?php echo ($directionB[$row]['Latitude']); ?>, lng: <?php echo($directionB[$row]['Longitude']); ?>}
    });


    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

    var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
    control.style.display = 'none';
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  }



  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    //var start = "41.850033,-87.6500523";//document.getElementById('start').value;
   // var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

    directionsService.route({
      origin: '<?php echo($direction['Latitude']); ?>,<?php echo($direction['Longitude']); ?>',
      destination: '<?php echo($directionB[$row]['Latitude']); ?>,<?php echo ($directionB[$row]['Longitude']); ?>',
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });  
  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have multiple maps, instead have one map with multiple routes to from source to destination in it, with some color difference based on the priority.

Example :

[image].

So try to loop the array of route and plot it on the graph.

Thank you,

Comment: Thanks ! but my problem is that i want multiple maps on single page.

Comment: This Answer would be appropriate for you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3