# How to add Multiple Google Maps on a single page

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

```js
//data structure below 
 var GPSData = [
    {
      media_name: "Ladybower.gpx",
      url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLadybower.gpx?alt=media&token=3f0e6a6a-51b4-4e03-a1ad-6244a7a0d8c1"
    },
    {
    media_name: "Linnet_Clough_.gpx",
    url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLinnet_Clough_.gpx?alt=media&token=df99a825-ad91-4e56-a11e-eb37b25aa819"
    }
]
  
// the loop to iterate over data above

let i;

 map = []
 ctaLayer = []
  for (i = 0; i < GPSData.length; i++) { 
        let htmlGPS = ""
        htmlGPS = `<div id="${GPSData[i].media_name}" class="mapNOs" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"> </div>`
      const foosGPS = document.querySelector('.foosGPS')
      foosGPS.innerHTML += htmlGPS      
      map[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(GPSData[i].media_name),{
              zoom: 11,
              center: {lat: 53.801277, lng: -1.548567}
            });
      ctaLayer[i] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                url: GPSData[i].url,
                map: map[i]
              });
   
  console.log('map', map[i], 'ctaLayer', ctaLayer[i])
}
```

```html
<div class="foosGPS"></div> 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZfMZulsytsTJzb3HRqIq9OT1ZqOuJNWA"></script>
```

So first I'll start with the endpoint of what should the user experience be when I eventually get this right. I have a mountain bike website that has area based trail listing pages for people to ride. On an area listing page, they can hit a GPS tab and it should open up row by row a list of Google KML maps showing x number of mountain bike trail maps listed one after the other which they see as they scroll down the page.

What they currently see is one box with a map and 1 empty boxs where another map should be.

I find loads of articles on getting multiple maps on the same map canvass i.e. multiple KML laters in the same map canvass but little on how to have them as unique map canvasses one after the other.

There is one article here [How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytdJJ.png) that gave me hope but it seems to work on the principle that the unique id's of the multiple divs on a page is hardcoded into the HTML or you dynamically create the div id's. But in my example, the challenge is more the variable name for the map needs to be dynamic and I can't work out how to generate that.

Using Firestore I have a "GPS" collection' which stores individual documents containing the reference to the KML url.

So I get the two docs from the Firestore collection and have them as an array I can then loop over.  In this example, it finds two docs, and as it cycles through each one and then using dynamic HTML updates the DOM and should in theory add on top the Google Maps using KML files.

In reality, it ends up showing two rows but it only shows one map at the end of the second row. I think I am struggling using an array to generate unique variable names for the var = map.

Any ideas or suggestions massively appreciated. I've included a code snippet so you can run and see. Been coding for a short period but love it. This challenge has stumped me.
Snippet attached

Console.log as follows:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
mapcopy.js:47 map ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 11, center: _.L, …}center: _.L {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}controls: (14) [empty, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]data: Mf {gm_accessors_: {…}, map: ni, gm_bindings_: {…}, i: tf, j: vf, …}features: {}gm_accessors_: {zoom: null, center: null, mapTypeId: null, streetView: null, bounds: {…}, …}gm_bindings_: {controlSize: {…}, reportErrorControl: {…}, zoom: {…}, center: {…}, mapTypeId: {…}, …}i: undefinedmapTypeId: "roadmap"mapTypes: {gm_accessors_: {…}, roadmap: fv, gm_bindings_: {…}, satellite: fv, hybrid: fv, …}overlayMapTypes: _.Ie {i: Array(0), gm_accessors_: {…}, length: 0, gm_bindings_: {…}, __e3_: {…}}streetView: Bg {__gm: {…}, W: null, i: _.Pe, H: null, o: null, …}tilesloading: truetilt: 0tosUrl: "https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB_US/help/terms_maps.html"zoom: 3__e3_: {center_changed: {…}, zoom_changed: {…}, projection_changed: {…}, tilt_changed: {…}, heading_changed: {…}, …}__gm: Dg {Na: div#Ladybower.gpx.mapNOs, i: Promise, j: _.Pe, ka: _.Je, copyrights: _.Ie, …}__proto__: Object ctaLayer hg {gm_accessors_: {…}, url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibiker…=media&token=3f0e6a6a-51b4-4e03-a1ad-6244a7a0d8c1", gm_bindings_: {…}, map: ni}$: falseH: i8 {i: _.Zf, j: Vd, gm_accessors_: {…}, gm_bindings_: {…}}T: Vd {j: _.Hs, o: "click", T: 0, id: 148, i: ƒ}defaultViewport: _.Id {Ya: Hd, Ua: Dd}gm_accessors_: {url: null, map: null, status: null, defaultViewport: null, metadata: null}gm_bindings_: {url: {…}, map: {…}, status: {…}, defaultViewport: {…}, metadata: {…}, …}i: []j: []ka: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLadybower.gpx?alt=media&token=3f0e6a6a-51b4-4e03-a1ad-6244a7a0d8c1"map: ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 3, center: _.L, …}metadata: {name: "", description: "", snippet: "", author: {…}, hasScreenOverlays: false}o: _.Hs {parameters: {…}, data: _.Je, layerId: "kml:cXOw0bjKUSqLpJ-PU5ay2LvzGlCqf8RDGf0mvwElV57DL-…dK4rUK6Mr8nAXLg5AnBiSEShUABJd1wqAgQuQ-OpLTDgU9ywI", Ch: true, zIndex: 0, …}screenOverlays_changed: ƒ ()status: "OK"ta: ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 3, center: _.L, …}ua: {ks: "ts:53094984", kv: "3", api: "3", client: "2"}url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLadybower.gpx?alt=media&token=3f0e6a6a-51b4-4e03-a1ad-6244a7a0d8c1"__e3_: {click: {…}, clickable_changed: {…}}__proto__: Object
mapcopy.js:47 map ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 11, center: _.L, …}center: _.L {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}controls: (14) [empty, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]data: Mf {gm_accessors_: {…}, map: ni, gm_bindings_: {…}, i: tf, j: vf, …}features: {}gm_accessors_: {zoom: null, center: null, mapTypeId: null, streetView: null, bounds: {…}, …}gm_bindings_: {controlSize: {…}, reportErrorControl: {…}, zoom: {…}, center: {…}, mapTypeId: {…}, …}i: undefinedmapDataProviders: "Map data ©2020"mapTypeId: "roadmap"mapTypes: {gm_accessors_: {…}, roadmap: fv, gm_bindings_: {…}, satellite: fv, hybrid: fv, …}mapUrl: "https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.391408,-2.015239&z=13&t=m&hl=en-GB&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3"overlayMapTypes: _.Ie {i: Array(0), gm_accessors_: {…}, length: 0, gm_bindings_: {…}, __e3_: {…}}rmiUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps/@53.3914077,-2.0152385,13z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&rapsrc=apiv3"streetView: Bg {__gm: {…}, W: null, i: _.Pe, H: null, o: null, …}tilesloading: falsetilt: 0tosUrl: "https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB_US/help/terms_maps.html"zoom: 13__e3_: {center_changed: {…}, zoom_changed: {…}, projection_changed: {…}, tilt_changed: {…}, heading_changed: {…}, …}__gm: Dg {Na: div#Linnet_Clough_.gpx.mapNOs, i: Promise, j: _.Pe, ka: _.Je, copyrights: _.Ie, …}__proto__: Object ctaLayer hg {gm_accessors_: {…}, url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibiker…=media&token=df99a825-ad91-4e56-a11e-eb37b25aa819", gm_bindings_: {…}, map: ni}$: falseH: i8 {i: _.Zf, j: Vd, gm_accessors_: {…}, gm_bindings_: {…}}T: Vd {j: _.Hs, o: "click", T: 0, id: 175, i: ƒ}defaultViewport: _.Id {Ya: Hd, Ua: Dd}gm_accessors_: {url: null, map: null, status: null, defaultViewport: null, metadata: null}gm_bindings_: {url: {…}, map: {…}, status: {…}, defaultViewport: {…}, metadata: {…}, …}i: []j: []ka: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLinnet_Clough_.gpx?alt=media&token=df99a825-ad91-4e56-a11e-eb37b25aa819"map: ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 13, center: _.L, …}metadata: {name: "", description: "", snippet: "", author: {…}, hasScreenOverlays: false}o: _.Hs {parameters: {…}, data: _.Je, layerId: "kml:cXOw0bjKUSqLpJ-PU5ay2LvzGlCqf8RDGf0mvwElV57DL-…W7UuaJIvTK6Ih8KbrR5f0GDUugFiS5qRXuKKQY95FQNU8l4CQ", Ch: true, zIndex: 0, …}screenOverlays_changed: ƒ ()status: "OK"ta: ni {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Dg, gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 13, center: _.L, …}ua: {ks: "ts:53094984", kv: "3", api: "3", client: "2"}url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ibikeride-38825.appspot.com/o/GPS%2F1693%2FLinnet_Clough_.gpx?alt=media&token=df99a825-ad91-4e56-a11e-eb37b25aa819"__e3_: {click: {…}, clickable_changed: {…}}__proto__: Object
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
injection.js:1 31:2.316@http://127.0.0.1:5501/map%20copy.html:content script injected
Grammarly.js:2 [DEFAULT]: WARN : Using DEFAULT root logger
t.printToConsole @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
t.logImpl @ Grammarly.js:2
e.log @ Grammarly.js:2
e.warn @ Grammarly.js:2
e.getRootLogger @ Grammarly.js:2
get @ Grammarly.js:2
e.getLogger @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
Grammarly.js:2 [WARNING] Using default timeseries implementation.
e.getRootMetric @ Grammarly.js:2
e @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
t.pipe @ Grammarly.js:2
e.rootLogLevelGetter @ Grammarly.js:2
u @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
n @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
(anonymous) @ Grammarly.js:2
injection.js:1 31:2.650@http://127.0.0.1:5501/map%20copy.html:session name : rebest2012_injected1592809563353
injection.js:1 31:2.651@http://127.0.0.1:5501/map%20copy.html:content script hasn't injected before.
injection.js:1 31:2.689@http://127.0.0.1:5501/map%20copy.html:result: {}
```

and here is what I see

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Display Multiple Google Maps per page with API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074520/how-to-display-multiple-google-maps-per-page-with-api-v3)

Comment: This article gave me hope when I read before posting but thanks as it may have the answer but I could not work it out...... it seems to work on the principle that the unique id's of the multiple divs on a page is hardcoded into the HTML but in my example, the div is a class and more it is generated dynamically as users themselves can add any number of maps to the page at any time hence they each have the same class name. Maybe I am missing something though in maybe you can dynamically generate unique classes or id names when injecting dynamic HTML?

Comment: Create the map based on an HTML element ID, which must be unique.

Comment: `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[i],...` (rather than an HTML element ID) should work.  Looks to me like the issue is the posted code is using the same value of `url` for all the maps. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your and @MrUpsidown help. I've updated the code in the post and spent a bit of time reviewing the other article. I've added a code snippet with comments and simplified the code ie a minimal reproducible example to make it easier to see. Thanks again

Comment: This is still not a [mcve]. You should provide at least a sample of your `GPSData` that can be used to reproduce the issue. Simplified data if you want, but we need to see the structure. Also you should provide any debugging info that you have. Errors in the JS console? Anything else?

Comment: Ok.. thank you for your patience. I am new at all this...but learning. I have simplified the snippet and included in it the map/ array of two of the documents that are looped over. I have also tried posting the console.log into the post. Hopefully a little clearer!! The console.log isnt' showing specific errors but i can see that although there is a specific data in both the KMLLayers for each map layer there is only specific data showing in the second map variable (the first is near empty) hence think it is related to that map variable somehow? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work. It's likely a bit of a hack and indicative of a wider issue on the page in the code but in essence I set a SetTimout function for 1 second around the var map elements, and now it works :)

```
//.......START OF GPS Tab ..........////
const allGPS = document.querySelectorAll('.modalGPS');

allGPS.forEach((all) => {
  all.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');

    const mediaCollection = db.collection('trails').doc(id).collection('GPS');

    mediaCollection
      // .where("media_type", "==", "GPS")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          const doc = change.doc;
          {
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              var storageRef = firebase
                .storage()
                .ref(doc.data().rel_path + doc.data().media_location);
              storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                addGPS(doc.data(), url);
              });
            } else {
              console.log('nought here');
            }
          }
        });
      });
  });
});

// ===GPS TAB function=====
const addGPS = (media, url) => {
  let htmlGPS = `
          <div id="${media.media_location}" class="mapNOs" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"> </div>
        `;

  const foosGPS = document.querySelector('.foosGPS');

  foosGPS.innerHTML += htmlGPS;

  function timeFunction() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById(media.media_location)
      );

      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: url,
        map: map,
      });

      console.log('map', map, 'layer', ctaLayer, 'url', url);
    }, 1000);
  }
  timeFunction();
};
```